# Saving data and displaying it in a form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a call report form with my contact's first name & contact's last name in my scaffold. Although I can clearly see the fields in the form and I can go ahead and edit them, the fields of `contact_first_name` & `contact_last_name` are always empty after being saved and returning to my view. I don't know what to do or how to approach this issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting your code would be very helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: Could be they aren't saving - check the database. Could be your view code, or corresponding controller code, is wrong. Posting that will help others help you.

Comment: @Steel Just going through  my database it looks as if all of the fields match, will go through my controller. Let me try and see.

Comment: @Steel Thank you for your suggestions there were two missing elements in my controller under the def job_params section. They have been edited and now it works! Thank you for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many problems:

1. contact_first_name or contact_last_name could be misspelled.
2. in controller they may not be permitted
3. you might be overriding these fields somewhere
4. etc etc

Possible solutions or the directions to the solution are:

1. check database for their existence
2. check spells
3. check them in permit list
4. check the logs

**But Code would be helping for both you and answering persons. So please post code with your question.**